# Arduino R3 Uno with EasyVR 3.0 Shield fails to connect to COM port

Tags: arduino, voice-recognition, arduino-uno

I have an Arduino Uno R3, an EasyVR 3.0 Shield (for voice recognition) Sketch 1.6.7 and Windows 7.
Unfortunately I failed early on in the process of uploading the EasyVR example code to Arduino (EasyVRBrdige and EasyVRTest).

When I remove the EasyVR shield the code upload works perfectly (and fail when it is mounted).

So I uploaded the EasyVRTest code when the EasyVR was unmounted 
Then mounted the EasyVR shield with its jumper at SW - but there is no response
from the Serial monitor (also tried PC and HW with same results)

In fact seems like the 'COM' port disappears in some cases from the Device Manager or in other only the Arduino 1.6.7 does not see it (not listed under Tools->Port:) although USB is connected and device manager list it.

I got the following messages in verbos mode:
*“Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
Board at COM12 is not available”*

Using EasyVR Commander at both SW and PC jumper modes say COM port cannot be opened.
The Arduino drivers are installed and up-to-date (Automatically detected by Windows 7). 
Using the USB power (no external power)

Any ideas?

I saw a hint in the post below that if Pin0 is connect that may cause such symptoms; how can I tell if EasyVR uses this Pin0?
http://www.instructables.com/id/A-solution-to-avrdude-stk500getsync-not-in-syn/

Comment: It's better to ask on http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: Going over the soldering of the pins, specially the TX and RX seem to solve the case